# Disable tax programmatically for a specific user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, tax

In my woocommerce web site, I have enable Tax in general WooCommerce settings.

I would like to disable tax for a specific user role programmatically ( with any hooks ), from my shop, checkout page and from order email.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**2020 update**

> You can't disable WooCommerce tax for a specific user role programmatically, **but you can apply for a specific user role a zero tax rate.**

First you need to have this specific user role set in worpress. If it's the case, let say that this custom user role is **`'resellers'`** for my code example.

Second, you have to enable in WooCommerce settings a **zero tax rate**:

[image]

And then for each country, you will have to set this **zero tax rate**:

[image]

**Third** - Then this hooked function will do the trick:

**Update - Since WooCommerce 3 use the following:**

```
function zero_rate_for_custom_user_role( $tax_class, $product ) {
    // Getting the current user 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_data = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    
    //  <== <== <== <== <== <== <== Here you put your user role slug 
    if ( in_array( 'resellers', $current_user_data->roles ) )
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

    return $tax_class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );
```

Before WooCommerce version 3 use the following:

```
function zero_rate_for_custom_user_role( $tax_class, $product ) {
    // Getting the current user 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_data = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    
    //  <== <== <== <== <== <== <== Here you put your user role slug 
    if ( in_array( 'resellers', $current_user_data->roles ) )
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

    return $tax_class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'zero_rate_for_custom_user_role', 10, 2 );
```

> You will just need to put instead of 'resellers' your desired user role slug.

*This code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.

Reference: [WooCommerce - Enabling "Zero rate" tax class to some specific user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836170/woocommerce-enabling-zero-rate-tax-class-to-some-specific-user-roles/39838828#39838828)

Comment: What if i want to disable for non logged in user?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the "Zero rate" is working fine for simple product but not working for Variation product. Please, help

Comment: This did not work for me on WooCommerce Version 5.2.2. It would be amazing if someone could update this and get it working for Woo 5+

Comment: @MattWilson Sorry but the composite hooks `woocommerce_product_get_tax_class` and `woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class`still work perfectly in WooCommerce last version, but it requires to enter product prices without taxes in order to get a visible difference when changing tax class programmatically.

Comment: There is error in example, function names are different in hooks "wc_diff_rate_for_user" when they should be "zero_rate_for_custom_user_role"