# Remove Tax based on Customer ID Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to remove the tax from order review woocommerce on the base of customer id. I tried to remove it by using the hook in the function.php file. But it does not work for me. Please help me.

see this screenshot for reference:

[image: see this image]

Comment: Where is the code that you tried? We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt, with more explanations.

Comment: Hi! I think you can find a place to start here: 
[Disable tax programmatically for a user specific role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972780/disable-tax-programmatically-for-a-specific-user-role)